# Alternative to triggers on system views for user auditing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, audit

Even writing the title I'm cringing at the idea I've tried this (*but hey, I've learned something in the process*).

I've got a problem with developers running migration scripts on the database and in the process overwriting stored procedures already existing in the database (DEV, *thank a deity*).

However, there's no way of finding out who made these changes because:

1. they don't admit it
2. SQL Server does not populate the `principal_id` column in the `sys.objects`  system view, because everyone is connecting as `dbo` ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255947/determine-what-user-created-objects-in-sql-server)).

So, I've tried writing a trigger on sys.objects and that didn't work (I don't know why I ever expected it to) as I'm getting a error:

> The object 'DEV_DB.sys.objects' does not exist or
>   is invalid for this operation.

I've also tried creating a user for each developer so that when they do their automatic migrations they will use the user I've made them and hopefully all changes made to `sys.objects` by that developer will be logged as the user they logged in with.

But that didn't work either, since `principal_id` still wasn't populated (*what I have done was create a new login / user for each Developer & DB and give the login [specific server roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles) : `public`, `db_datawriter`, `db_datareader`, `db_ddladmin`*).

Any suggestions on what else I could try as an alternative?

Comment: You could try http://dbhistory.com , this is exactly the scenario it targets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always tap up the default trace to catch any changes to objects, including stored procs.

Give the following script a whirl, it's easy enough to find out who changed what and when.  It's helped me catch out more than one sly developer ;)

```
SELECT  t.DatabaseName, t.ObjectID,t.NTUserName,t.HostName,t.StartTime, te.name
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\Log\log.trc', DEFAULT) t  
JOIN sys.trace_events te  on t.EventClass = te.trace_event_id  
ORDER BY t.StartTime DESC;
```

You'll need to change the path to wherever your SQL trace file is, to find out where it is run:

```
select path 
from sys.traces
where id = 1
```

One tip, remove the `_number` from the file name to read all available trace files e.g. if the file name is `log_16.trc`, change it to `log.trc`.

Answer (score 2):

If the developers have individual logins, you might consider a DDL Trigger. Here's an example for the `CREATE_PROCEDURE`, `ALTER_PROCEDURE`, and `DROP_PROCEDURE` events.

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgStoredProcDDL
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE
AS
BEGIN
    --Get relevant info from EVENTDATA()
    DECLARE @Login SYSNAME= EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'SYSNAME');
    DECLARE @DBUser SYSNAME = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)[1]', 'SYSNAME');
    DECLARE @Schema SYSNAME = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'SYSNAME');
    DECLARE @Proc SYSNAME = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'SYSNAME');

    --Optional: error message for end user.
    RAISERROR ('Please stop!', 16, 1);

    --Optional: Rollback transaction that fired the DDL trigger
    ROLLBACK;

    --Optional: log some data to a table.
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO guest.LogTable(LogMsg, LogDate, [Login], [User])
        VALUES('Stored Proc was created/altered/dropped: [' + @Schema + '].[' + @Proc+ ']', 
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            @Login,
            @DBUser);
    COMMIT

    --Optional: send an email/alert.
    DECLARE @Subj NVARCHAR(255) 
    SET @Subj = @@SERVERNAME + ' - Stored Proc created/altered/dropped'
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = 'You@YourDomain.com', 
        @subject = @Subj,
        @body = 'Your message...'
END;
```

Here's a blog post about handling events with DDL triggers with some further explanation: [SQL Server Event Handling: DDL Events](https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2016/07/SQL-Server-Event-Handling-DDL-Events.html)